# How to get the git tag name in Jenkins in Node configuration

Tags: git, jenkins, nunit

We re using node configuration in Jenkins.In the Post-build Actions we have Git Publisher which has tags to Push e.g 5.1.0.$BUILD_NUMBER.This now becomes the new build number and is used as the release number for testing

I wanted to access this tag for all the remaining jobs so that I can create the Test report XMLs something  with 5.1.0.$BUILD_NUMBER+myjob.xml so that its related to that unique build number.

However I am not sure how can I retrieve the Git tags in all the individual jobs.I am not too sure that I want to use Global  variable string property since its a node configuration where on one node/box there a different build and on other there is a different one.The Global property could overwrite the build versions on each other ?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to pick a tag when running a new job, you can use the [Git Parameter Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Parameter+Plugin). With this plugin you have new options when you add parameters to your job.

> This plugin allows you to assign git tag or revision number as parameter in Parametrized builds.
>   There is no need to set up anything special, this plugin will read your default configuration from Git Plugin.
>
> It firstly fetching (by git fetch) current repository, and listing all the tags/sha1's to choose from.
>
> You can select the following sorting options for tags/revision/branches/branches_or_tags
>
> - none
> - descending
> - ascending
> - ascending smart
> - descending smart
>
> For the smart variants the compare treats a sequence of digits as a single character. Contributed by Graeme Hill.

---

There is also the [Git Tag Message Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Tag+Message+Plugin) which, for any build, will discover if any tag is matching the current commit used for the build. If a tag is found, it's name will be set in the `GIT_TAG_NAME` environment variable.

> Exports the name and message for a git tag as environment variables during a build.
>
> If the revision checked out during a build has a git tag associated with it, its name will be exported during the build as the GIT_TAG_NAME environment variable.
>   If a message was specified when creating the tag (e.g. via git tag -m "..."), then that message will also be exported during the build, as the GIT_TAG_MESSAGE > environment variable.
>
> If the revision has more than one tag associated with it, only the most recent tag will be taken into account. However, if your refspec includes "refs/tags" — i.> e. builds are only triggered when certain tag names or patterns are matched — then the exact tag name that triggered the build will be used, even if it's not the most recent tag for this commit.

Comment: Tried GIT_TAG_NAME it does not o/p anything in following command.The Git branch and build number works echo  Git branch is %GIT_BRANCH%

echo Build number is %BUILD_NUMBER%

echo Git Revision is %GIT_COMMIT%

 echo Git Tag is %GIT_TAG_MESSAGE%

Comment: we are already generating the Tag name with 5.1.0.$BUILD_NUMBER in the first job in Jenkins.Its more about how do I make it available to other jobs as well.I tried global variable,however at Global level the BUILD_NUMBER is not available so I am bit stuck.

Comment: with the Git Tag Message plugin, you can pass to other jobs just the _commit hash_ that matches the tag, and the plugin will figure out which tag matches.

Comment: .Not too sure how I can get the commit hash.So everyday there are many commits to a branch.We then push a tag E.g.5.1.0.$BUILD_NUMBER which is now our revision number.Now say if there are 10 jobs which are triggered after  the build there is possibility at say job nos 3-4 to get the wrong tag(as developers would be commiting and pushing stuff and therefore the tag can change from job1 to job3-4). I want the revision number with tag 5.1.0.$BUILD_NUMBER to be pretty much consistent till the next build is trgiggered.Cant I write this to file and read it later on.But not sure how?