# How do I see if a jenkins pipeline was run from a git tag from inside the pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I can get the branch from inside a jenkins multibranch pipeline like this:

```
env.BRANCH_NAME
```

But I have discover tags enabled.

How do I:

1. See if the job was started from a tag (instead of branch)
2. See the name of the tag is was started from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Git Tag Message plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Git+Tag+Message+Plugin) for any build and it will discover if any tag is matching the current commit used for the build. If a tag is found, it's name will be set in the **GIT_TAG_NAME** environment variable.

For further you can [refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32390788/how-to-get-the-git-tag-name-in-jenkins-in-node-configuration).